# best way to read data from flat file and write it to xml

Tags: java, xml, file

I have a flat .txt file with comma seprated values in a row, something like :

```
1,name1,department1
2,name2,department2
3,name3,department3
...
...
```

Now I want to read these records from .txt file and write it to xml, and the output should be something like :

```
<Employees>
     <Employee>
          <Code>1</Code>
          <Name>name1</Name>
          <Department>department1</Department>
     </Employee>
     <Employee>
          <Code>2</Code>
          <Name>name2</Name>
          <Department>department2</Department>
     </Employee>
     <Employee>
          <Code>3</Code>
          <Name>name3</Name>
          <Department>department3</Department>
     </Employee>
</Employees>
```

So now to achieve this I have gone through with various questions/posts, somehow I am confused with the approach that I should follow and which XMLBuilder I should use, like XStream ?

Can anybody tell me that which approach I should follow in order to achieve the best performance ?

Comment: For one, you don't need an xml parser yet, you need an xml builder.

Comment: How many times do you need to do this? Are there any `<` etc. characters in your file? The easiest way might just be search-and-replace with a text editor

Comment: Also, will you change the xml format often or is it stable/static.

Comment: @artbristol well the flat file might of a large size and needs execute this process every 1 or 2 days...

Comment: @count0 The format will remain the same....

Comment: @user1646267 I have been working with XML in the [tag:vb.net] framework alot recently.  First off take your CSV structure and normalize it like a database.  Take that basic structure and then design the flow of how you want it to look in XML.  You always start with the outer XMLElement (parent) and work your way down to the dead-end Elements.  Its not an easy tasks and can get very confusing.  I do alot of `XDoc.Save(filename)` periodically to output test what i have built so far so i can keep track of what i have done ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a CSV library such as openCSV to read the file, then use JAXB to create the XML file.

You can create an `Employees` class with a `List<Employee>` where `Employee` has fields `Code`, `Name` etc. Fill it in using the CSV library. Use one of the `JAXB.marshal` methods to write the whole thing out to a file in one line.

Simple example code

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
public class XmlWriterTest
{
    public String foo;
    public List<String> bars;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        XmlWriterTest test = new XmlWriterTest();
        test.foo = "hi";
        test.bars = Arrays.asList("yo", "oi");
        JAXB.marshal(test, System.out);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way in psuedocode:

```
file.write("<Employees>");
foreach(String line : file)
{
    String[] parts = line.split(",");
    file.write("<Employee><Code>" + parts[0] + "</Code><Name>" + parts[1] + "</Name><Department>" + parts[2] + "</Department></Employee>");
}
file.write("</Employees>");
```

Obviously this solution is very naive and assumes your flat file doesn't contain commas in fields and every line has exactly 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, the easiest way seems to be to just do this without any xml builder using print/write:

1. read txt file line by line
2. split fields using "," as the separator
3. write in xml markup to file/stdout using simple System.out.print method

Don't forget the XML header.

If your format changes frequently, you'd write a `.xsd schema` and use `jaxb` to generate a class hierarchy and marshalling/unmarshalling code, but in this case it would be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

How about a one line awk solution?

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{printf "<Employees>\n"}END{printf "</Employees>\n"}{printf"<Employee><Code>%s</Code><Name>%s</Name><Department>%s</Department></Employee>\n",$1,$2,$3}' data.txt
```

Writing a Java program would seem to be overkill for such a simple problem.

### Update

If you want output formated you can pipe it into the xmllint command:

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{printf "<Employees>"}END{printf "</Employees>"}{printf"<Employee><Code>%s</Code><Name>%s</Name><Department>%s</Department></Employee>",$1,$2,$3}' data.txt | xmllint --format -
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <Code>1</Code>
    <Name>name1</Name>
    <Department>department1</Department>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Code>2</Code>
    <Name>name2</Name>
    <Department>department2</Department>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Code>3</Code>
    <Name>name3</Name>
    <Department>department3</Department>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```